# FluentAssertions: string does not contain a definition for ShouldBeEquivalentTo

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions, nspec

I am trying to use Nspec.  I have followed these instructions: http://nspec.org/

1. Create a class library project
2. Nuget: Install-Package nspec
3. Nuget: Install-Package FluentAssertions
4. Create a class file and paste the following code:

---

```
using NSpec;
using FluentAssertions;

class my_first_spec : nspec
{
    string name;

    void before_each()
    {
        name = "NSpec";
    }

    void it_asserts_at_the_method_level()
    {
        name.ShouldBeEquivalentTo("NSpec");
    }

    void describe_nesting()
    {
        before = () => name += " Add Some Other Stuff";

        it["asserts in a method"] = () =>
        {
            name.ShouldBeEquivalentTo("NSpec Add Some Other Stuff");
        };

        context["more nesting"] = () =>
        {
            before = () => name += ", And Even More";

            it["also asserts in a lambda"] = () =>
            {
                name.ShouldBeEquivalentTo("NSpec Add Some Other Stuff, And Even More");
            };
        };
    }
}
```

The editor recognises the namespaces and the nspec class, however I see a compiler error that says:

> 'string does not contain a definition for ShouldBeEquivalentTo'.

What is the problem?

I am using .NET 4.7.1 and Visual Studio 2017.

I have spent some time Googling this and I have looked here for example: https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/234

Comment: @CodeCaster, could you clarify what you mean.  I am just following the instructions.  The code is on the webpage I link to.

Comment: Well, that sample is wrong/outdated. It happens. In recent versions of FluentAssertions, that's written `.Should().BeEquivalentTo()`.

Comment: https://github.com/nspec/NSpec/issues/161

Answer (score 17, accepted):

FluentAssertions has removed `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` extension as a breaking change in more recent versions.

Refer to the recent FluentAssertions documentation for the suggested alternative

https://fluentassertions.com/introduction

```
name.Should().BeEquivalentTo(...);
```

Your example code would need to be updated to

```
class my_first_spec : nspec {
    string name;

    void before_each() {
        name = "NSpec";
    }

    void it_asserts_at_the_method_level() {
        name.Should().BeEquivalentTo("NSpec");
    }

    void describe_nesting() {
        before = () => name += " Add Some Other Stuff";

        it["asserts in a method"] = () => {
            name.Should().BeEquivalentTo("NSpec Add Some Other Stuff");
        };

        context["more nesting"] = () => {
            before = () => name += ", And Even More";

            it["also asserts in a lambda"] = () => {
                name.Should().BeEquivalentTo("NSpec Add Some Other Stuff, And Even More");
            };
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works as expected.  Would you put your Nspec tests in a separate Visual Studio project to your Specflow scenarios?

Comment: can you answer the question in my comment above? Then I will mark your answer.

Comment: @w0051977: That's not how stack overflow works! If you have another question, post a new one. This is not a forum, tutoring or discussion site. If the answer solved your original question, accept it. Please take the mandatory [tour] again to recap site-rules.

Comment: Ahh... this works for Strings but doesn't seem to work for Int's. Seems Ints is `.Should().Be(...)`

Comment: @Nkosi - I was using `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` to compare lists of custom types, it was nicely comparing object public properties, wondering if you could suggest how to do this when ShouldBeEquivalentTo is not availablle anymore?

Comment: @sll `.Should().BeEquivalentTo` should (*pardon the pun*) work for your assertions as well.